# If any cell in range is not "" (empty)

Tags: excel-formula

What is the formula to display value from translation worksheet is any cell in range is not blank?

I have range `B24:B254` where cells return `=""`. I need formula to display `X` if any of cells in range `B24:B254` is not `=""`

I have tried this one but it does not work:

```
=IF(COUNTA(B24:B254)="";"";"X")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit convoluted, but try this:

```
COUNTA(B24:B254)-(COUNTBLANK(B24:B254)-COUNTIF(B24:B254,"<>*"))
```

> `COUNTA(B24:B254)`
>   How many cells contain Values or Formula.  This **will** include `=""`

> `COUNTBLANK(B24:B254)`
>   How many cells contain Blank Values.  This **will** include `=""`

> `COUNTIF(B24:B254,"<>*")`
>   How many cells contain No Values or Formula.  This **will not** include `=""`

Now, this means that `(COUNTBLANK(B24:B254)-COUNTIF(B24:B254,"<>*"))` is "Cells with Blank Values" minus "Cells without values or Formula", which gives you how many `=""` cells there are.

You then subtract this from the "Cells with Values and Formula" number (`COUNTA(B24:B254)`) to get "Cells with non-blank Values and Formula" (i.e. Exclude `=""` from `COUNTA`)